# How to get ID of any cast using tmdb api?

Tags: jquery, api, themoviedb-api

I want to get ID of particular cast using tmdb api. After that I will use that cast id to discover all the movies of that cast.

I just want to know is it possible to fetch Id of any cast by its name?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this API Endpoint: /search/person.
This allows to search for people by name.
Please check the [API documentation](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/search/searchperson) and look for section: /search.

For example:

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=###&search_type=ngram&query=julia

Hope it helped.